# How can I set android font family to make the width the same?

Tags: android

The text of tvA include two spaces, and tvB include one space.
but in UI, the width of the two control are not same.
I hope the width both tvA and tvB the same, how do do? Thanks!

```
 <TextView
   android:id="@+id/tvA"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="1  2" />


 <TextView
   android:id="@+id/tvB"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="3 45" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default droidsans font is not Monospaced Font, so you can not make "wrap_content" textviews to be the same width. To do this, you have to use some customized font.

You should use some fonts like "courier new". Pack the ttf file with your APK(in assets folder) and do this in your code:

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
        "fonts/CourierNew.ttf");
TextView tva = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvA);
TextView tvb = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvB);
tva.setTypeface(tf);
tvb.setTypeface(tf);
```

Comment: Why downvote? Default droidsans font is not Monospaced Font, so you can not make  "wrap_content" textviews to be the same width. To do this, you have to use some customized font. Am I misunderstanding the question or providing a wrong answer?

Comment: I thought you had answered for how to set font. I misunderstood.

Comment: It is OK. It was also my fault for not elaborating my answer. I have modified it and hope it could help.

Comment: Thanks! Can I copy windows 7 font cour.ttf to assets\fonts folder and use windows font?

Comment: Yes I think you can. And you can also google to get a lot of download resources. Tell us if it works.